# Vlookup for all sheets in an Excel workbook with VBA loop is not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to perform the same function(a VLookup off of a table in a separate Excel workbook) on each sheet in a workbook. I have a VBA script built, but the loop is not working. The VLookup will work on whatever sheet I am on, but will not cycle through the rest.

Script:

```
Sub loop_through_all_worksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Range("AE2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], [Vendor.xlsx]AP210!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
        Range("AE2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE2:AE49")
        Range("AE2:AE49").Select
        Columns("AE:AE").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                               SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        starting_ws.Activate
    Next
End Sub
```

Notes:
'Vendor.xlsx' is the lookup table that is in a 2nd file.

I pieced this together from making my own VLookup script and adding it to a loop script I found.

The number of tabs and the names of each tab are vaiable

Any input on why the loop is not working? Am I totally off base with this?

Thank you, in advance, for the help

Comment: You're looping through all the worksheets in `ThisWorkbook` but performing a single `VLOOKUP` in an external workbook? It looks like the same `VLOOKUP` each time. If so, you can move it outside the loop. Also, you [don't have to use `Select` and `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201705232001577159123)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid `.Select` and `.Activate`

use with blocks and set the parent worksheet with the loop object.

```
Sub loop_through_all_worksheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
    Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws.Range("AE2:AE49")
           .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], [Vendor.xlsx]AP210!C1:C2,2,FALSE)"
           .Value = .Value
        End With        
    Next
    starting_ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, Thank you for the script. I used what you suggested and it worked once. I then save it in the macro and reran to test and now it is only doing a vlookup on the xlsb file, not the intended file.

Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Files in consideration:
1) XLSX file that has the multiple tabs, this is the file the vlookups should be performed in
2)'Vendor.xlsx--this has the reference/vlookup table
3)Macro.XLSB

Comment: You will need to reference the workbook on which you want the code to run.  You will need to change `ThisWorkbook` to `Workbooks("Vendor.xlsx")`  This workbook refers the the workbook in which the code resides.

Comment: Scott,
Wouldn't I need to update the 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets' to the name of the file that all the tabs in it? In this case, 'Apr_17_Division_1_7_tabs.xlsx'?

If yes, would I change it to Apr_17_Division_1_7_tabs.xlsx.worksheets or just Apr_17_Division_1_7_tabs.xlsx?

Again, appreciate your help!

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that the workbook was called `Vendor.xlsx`  refer to the note above and change the name to the name it should be.

Comment: Scott,

Hoping you can help me with the next section of this script...

After doing the vlookup, I need to separate each worksheet in the workbook into its own file.

I have the below script, but it is not working. It doesn't fail and give me an error, it just doesn't do anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sub Splitbook()
    MyPath = "***Folder Location***"
    For Each sht In Workbooks("PO135 Division 1.xlsx").Worksheets
    sht.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
    Filename:=MyPath & "\" & sht.Name & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Next sht
    End Sub

Comment: new question = new post

Comment: Sorry Scott, good call
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164041/vba-script-to-split-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook-to-separate-files